# Type pattern matching and inference error in Scala 3

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, type-level-computation, scala-3

I'm playing with type classes in Scala 3, and got to a compilation error that I can't explain.

Considering the following code:

```scala
trait Transformation[Input, Output <: Tuple]:
  def apply(x: Input): Output


trait ListOfTransformations[T[_, _] <: Transformation[_, _], Input <: Tuple, Output <: Tuple] extends Transformation[Input, Output]

object ListOfTransformations:
  given empty[T[_, _] <: Transformation[_, _]]: ListOfTransformations[T, EmptyTuple, EmptyTuple] with
    def apply(t: EmptyTuple): EmptyTuple = t

  given nonEmpty[T[_, _] <: Transformation[_, _], Head, Tail <: Tuple, HeadOutput <: Tuple, TailOutput <: Tuple](
    using
    ht: T[Head, HeadOutput],
    tt: ListOfTransformations[T, Tail, TailOutput]
  ): Transformation[Head *: Tail, Tuple.Concat[HeadOutput, TailOutput]] with
    def apply(x: Head *: Tail): Tuple.Concat[HeadOutput, TailOutput] = ht(x.head) ++ tt(x.tail)
```

I get:

```
Found:    Tuple.Head[Head² *: Tail]
Required: nonEmpty.this.ht.Input

where:    Head  is a type in object Tuple which is an alias of [X <: NonEmptyTuple] =>> 
  X match {
    case [x, _ <: Tuple] =>> scala.runtime.MatchCase[x *: _, x]
  }
          Head² is a type in class nonEmpty
          Tail  is a type in class nonEmpty with bounds <: Tuple
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `Head` is both a type parameter to `nonEmpty`, as well as a type defined in the `Tuple`-object (see here: https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/Tuple$.html#Head-0). Maybe the compiler thinks you are referencing Tuple.Head somewhere instead of the type parameter, or vice versa? Could you try renaming your type parameter to something else?

Comment: @marstran I renamed it to `H` and the error message changed (weirdly) but it didn't go away:
Found:    Tuple.Head[H *: Tail]
Required: nonEmpty.this.ht.Input
where:    Tail is a type in class nonEmpty with bounds <: Tuple

Comment: the fact that the error has changed confuses me even more since there's no import of `Tuple.Head` anywhere, so it shouldn't be confused with it

Comment: this is the example btw:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0qRSPun5QIe9vsK70EVYuw

Comment: `Tail` is also a type in `Tuple`. Try to rename that one as well.

Comment: I did, it didn't help: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7keZNItcR2qzRM0ZM0nCig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When taking type constructors with bounds as type parameters, make sure you use actual arguments instead of wildcards. Using `T[a, b] <: Transformation[a, b]` instead of `T[_, _] <: Transformation[_, _]` lets it compile ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/n9jjZVmvQQCmVzKqmrbH4g)). The former takes a type constructor that, when given two types, gives a type that is a subtype of `Transformation[a, b]` for some `a` and `b` that we don't know. By not using wildcards (and ignoring the actual parameters of `T`), you're letting the compiler know precisely what a `T[a, b]` is a subtype of.